# Image Rendering using Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi  i'm developing an iPhone app with cocos2D framework for image rendering .
How we can split the image into layer for example consider an house image here i want to spilt the roof of the house ,door,wall etc and i want to change there respective colors or images can any one help me in this.! I needed some example code also for it .
Please  help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different layer for different depth of rendering.

You can read more about Cocos2D programming here: [Click Here](http://cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/index.html)

Get Cocos2D SDK and run some sample test applications. [DOWNLOAD SDK HERE](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download)

Comment: Thankq for u r reply any sample code for image rendering as i mention in above

Comment: @naga, yes before that you must learn what is z order and how layer concept works. Best of luck.

Comment: i have learn the basic concepts ofv cocos2D like cclayer, sprite, direction scene etc… right now i am trying to  rendering an image as i mentioned above i am able to change the entire color of an image but unable to change color of particular layers of an image example roof of an image

Comment: Can you please send me sample code how to do this

Comment: @naga, See LayerTest and SpriteTest sample in cocos2d sdk